# Log Azure Function Request as failed and return status 200

Tags: azure-functions, azure-application-insights

I have a azure function V3 in dotnet. In case of an application error, the function returns a status 200 and a json with an error property. (like graphql is doing it.)

If an error occurs, Application insights shows this Request as successful:

[image: Successful request]

Since it is much easier to identify and alert on unsuccessful, I would prefer if this is logged with `Successful request: false`.

Is there a way to return status 200, but set the Request for logging to failed?

Comment: Does this log automatically collect by application insights? And in azure function -> Monitor, is it still the same info like "Successful request: true"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `successful request` is not changeable.

In function v2, we can use [ITelemetryInitializer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/api-filtering-sampling#addmodify-properties-itelemetryinitializer) to add a custom property like Is_success as false for your case.

But in function v3, currently, there is some issues when use [ITelemetryInitializer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/api-filtering-sampling#addmodify-properties-itelemetryinitializer).

Comment: Thanks for the info. I will give a try in the new year.